# How to look for a single value in a set of tuples?

Tags: python, set, tuples

Suppose I have this set:

```
a = set([(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)])
```

How do I test if "3" or "7" can be found in that set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#any):

```
any(3 in t or 7 in t for t in a)
```

Comment: perhaps this may be clearer: `any(3 in tup for tup in setOfTuples)`

Comment: +1 very clear. @ninjagecko that would just give a NameError ;-)

Comment: @ChrisWesseling: yes, obviously =) I assumed the reader would realize that `setOfTuples` was clearly `a`

Answer (score 2):

```
a = set([(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)])
b = set((3,7))
any(b&set(p) for p in a)
# True
```

@RikPoggi also proposed using `isdisjoint`, which works even without creating a set:

```
any(not b.isdisjoint(p) for p in a)
```

Comment: From python-2.7 you could use `b = {3,7}`, and that last line could also be: `any(not b.isdisjoint(set(p)) for p in a)`

Comment: -1: You've written a tautology: `>>> a = set([(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)])
>>> b = set((8,7))
>>> any(b|set(p) for p in a)
True
`; neither 8 or 7 is in a yet I get True. @RikPoggi's *is* right.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling - you're right, wrong operator (*or* instead of *and*), thank you, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

```
for tuple in a:
    for value in tuple:
        if value in [3, 7]:
            print 'found'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> if set(chain(*set([(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)])))&set([3,7]):
...     print True
...     
True
```